# Easier way to assign a value to multiple global variables in a function

Tags: python

I declared a few global variables in a python file and would like to reset their values to None in a function. Is there a better/hack/pythonic way to declare all variables as global and assign them a value in one line?

```
doctype, content_type, framework, cms, server = (None,)*5

def reset():
        doctype, content_type, framework, cms, server = (None,)*5
```

Comment: I'd be deeply suspicious of a design which depended on that many global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to get a reference to the dict of global variables:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
>>> globals().update({'a': 2})
>>> a
2
>>>
```

In your case:

```
globals().update({
    'doctype': None,
    'content_type': None,
    ...
})
```

Use a dict comprehension to do this in one line:

Or this:

```
for var_name in ('doctype', 'content_type', 'framework', 'cms', 'server'):
     globals()[var_name] = None
```

Or this:

```
module = sys.modules[__name__]
for var_name in ('doctype', 'content_type', 'framework', 'cms', 'server'):
     setattr(var_name, None)
```

Comment: Is this really easier?

Comment: @zhangxaochen, it's more versatile. If you have more variables, or you keep variable names in a list - this is easier

Answer (score 2):

Chain `=`, since you're assining immutable `None` to them:

```
doctype = content_type = framework = cms = server = None
```

If you wanna use the `reset` function, you have to declare them as `global` inside it:

```
def reset():
    global doctype, content_type, framework, cms, server
    doctype = content_type = framework = cms = server = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **one** global mutable object in this case, `dict` for example:

```
conf = dict.fromkeys(['doctype', 'content_type', 'framework', 'cms', 'server'])

def reset():
    for k in conf:
        conf[k] = None
```

or class. This way you can incapsulate `reset` in class itself:

```
class Config():
    doctype = None
    content_type = None
    framework = None
    cms = None
    server = None

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):   
        for attr in [i for i in cls.__dict__.keys()
                     if i[:1] != '_' and not hasattr(getattr(cls, i), '__call__')]:
            setattr(cls, attr, None)
```